# Список полей в объекте

Tags: python, python-2.x

Я получаю некий объект с неизвестными для меня полями. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ стандартными средствами `Python` посмотреть список полей данного объекта ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Штатный: `dir(obj)`
Кроме того, часто полезно явно запросить тип: `type(obj)`

Comment: а список методов ?

Comment: В списке, который отдаёт dir присутствуют и поля и методы.